# Does using full resources of server ensures better query execution performance?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, doparallel

```
Create table hp_zzz1
nologging parallel
as
select * fom hP_zzz;
```

I am using CTAS to create a new table. As i have used parallel hint, without any parallel threads. Its consuming 256 DOP of exadata server.

1. Does this query performs at max level. Or this will consume more time??
2. Does using full resources of server guarantee execution of query?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using more resources for a parallel Oracle SQL statement will typically result in better performance and run in less time.

[image]
[image]

In theory, it would make sense that using too high a degree of parallelism (DOP) would eventually become counter-productive.  At some point the overhead of managing such a large number of parallel processes could out-weigh the benefit of extra processes.

But in practice I have never seen this happen with Oracle SQL statements.  I've bench marked this a few times, on several different platforms, for both CPU and I/O bound tasks.  It seems like bigger is always better.

But there are many important disclaimers:

1. Although a higher DOP will help that one statement it may be massively unfair to other statements.  There is certainly a point of diminishing returns.  It may not be a good idea to increase the performance of one statement by less than 1% if it hurts many other statements.
2. Although I've tested this several times I can't guarantee it's true for every configuration.
3. Testing these scenarios is difficult.  You have to pick a large amount of work, on a system that other people aren't using, try to avoid a "hot" system by running things like `alter system flush buffer_cache` (although that may not disable OS caching), run the tests multiple times, remove outliers, average the results, etc.
4. Watch out for Oracle mechanisms that may reduce the DOP.  Just because you ask for 256 doesn't mean you'll get 256.  To ensure that parameters or throttling isn't happening, check `v$px_process` to ensure that all the parallel threads are being used.

In my experience, if you only care about the best performance for a single SQL statement, crank the DOP as high as possible.