# Oracle index performance options

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing

I am going to be building an index for a table with 5 billion records. Nologging and parallel will be used but is there any other options or tricks I can use to speed up the creation of the index build?

Comment: If you partition the table and have locally partitioned indexes it might be better than building one large index all at once. Not sure that it will be faster but you can do a partition at a time and if you get interrupted you can restart where you were.

Comment: This is generally good advice with large, locally partitioned indexes. Especially if there's a chance you don't have sufficient temp space to complete the full build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to parallelism and nologging, these features may be able to improve index creation time:

1. **Compression** - Compression takes extra CPU time but uses less I/O. This option *might* save time in some circumstances, like if you have a highly compressible multi-column index.
2. **NOSORT** - If the rows happen to be inserted in order, like if you just loaded presorted data, the `NOSORT` option can save a significant amount of time.
3. **Don't regather statistics** - Statistics are automatically gathered when an index is built, so don't manually gather index statistics afterwards. And if you're going to gather table statistics, use the argument `cascade => false` to prevent regathering index statistics.

I agree with Paul W that getting the right degree of parallelism is probably the most important factor. If you want to optimize this statement, and don't care about the performance of anything else that is running at the same time, [crank the DOP as high as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47245489/409172).

But I'm skeptical of using partitioning to speed up index creation. Since sorting is O(n*log(n)), it should usually be faster to sort one large set than to sort multiple smaller sets.

Answer (score 1):

Using the right degree of parallelism is the main thing. `NOLOGGING` will help as well on the block loading stage at the end. Lastly, you should ensure you have a large amount of PGA available so you don't do a multipass sort. Check '`global memory bound`' in `v$pgastat` and if it's less than 1G (the maximum value), raise `pga_aggregate_target` until the global memory bound reaches 1G. Or, you can enable manual PGA and set your `sort_area_size` to the maximum value:

```
ALTER SESSION SET workarea_size_policy=manual;
ALTER SESSION SET sort_area_size=1073741823;
```

Now each of your PX threads will get 1G of PGA assigned. Just make sure you have that much available memory on the host. Because it's assigned to each PX thread, raising your DOP can increase the amount done in memory rather than on disk, in addition to assigning more workers on the build. You don't have much hope of doing this entirely in memory with 5 billion records, but at least you'll optimize the use of PGA as best you can before spilling to temp workareas.